# Align cell textLabel to top left programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have programmatically created a TableView using sections in swift. The amount of sections and rows will always be the same, as they're just displaying info that I pull in from Firebase.

I would like to change the textLabel of one of the cells to align to the top, instead of the middle of the cell. All other textLabels I would like to remain centered. The cell in question is section 1, row 1.

It currently looks like:

[image]

I've been looking for how to do this for a while, and a lot of people say to do:

```
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
```

But this isn't working. I'm placing this code in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
         if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.textLabel!.text = "Our review"
         } else {
            cell.textLabel!.text = film?.Main_Review
            cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0      // HERE
            cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()            // HERE
         }
}
```

Nothing happens, the text still aligns to centre of the cell.

Does anyone know a simple way of doing this? Preferably without having to create a custom cell (as this only needs to effect 1 row)? Thanks

**UPDATE** - All code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: cellId)

    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 14)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 14)


    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.textLabel!.text = "Share"
        }
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.textLabel!.text = "Our review"
        } else {
            cell.textLabel!.text = film?.Main_Review
            cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
        }
    } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.textLabel!.text = "UK release date"
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = film?.Date_Released?.capitalizedString
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell.textLabel!.text = "Directed by"
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = film?.Directed_By?.capitalizedString
        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            cell.textLabel!.text = "Running time"
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = film?.Running_Time
        } else {
            cell.textLabel!.text = "Certificate rating"
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = film?.Certificate_Rating
        }
    }

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Can you please tell how this condition ever going to success `if indexPath.section == 0 {  if indexPath.section == 1 {`, how it is possible

Comment: @NDoc Thanks! That was my mistake - updated now.

Comment: write all `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @Vyacheslav Added the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: What is your objection to using a different cell for the first row? It's quite easy to do that.

Comment: @Abizern I just assumed that as its only 1 row I needed to be different it would be a lot more work? Could you maybe provide an answer explaining how to achieve this with a custom cell? Thanks

Comment: I've just had a look at your code - why are you using a tableView, why not a custom view?

Comment: @Abizern Because a tableView has the majority of what I need. In fact, the only thing I want to be able to do extra is align one `textLabel` to the top in one cell. It has all the scrollView set up perfect for the screen and allows me to nicely present my content. Why would I not use the tableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cell.textLabel is a default label in UITableViewCell. If you want your text to start at the top you should create a subclasse of UITableViewCell and create your own view for this cell.
For example

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {

var label : UILabel!

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.label = UILabel()
    self.contentView.addSubview(label)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.label.frame = CGRectMake(15,10,200,30)
    self.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    self.label.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()

}
```

}

Then in your viewController dont forget to use the register class method like this

```
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.registerClass(ItemCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```

And in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
let cell:ItemCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier") as? ItemCell
```

Comment: @MatGrit Thanks for this. I have done as you said, but the label doesn't show. There is no error, just blank now for that row. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MatGrit Also, what do you mean by `self.descr.frame.maxY+10` ?

Comment: My bad, Instead of self.descr put 10. You Also need to add some text in the label. To debug try adding a backgroundcolor to the label.

Comment: @MatGrit That fixed it, thanks! Achieved what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
```

should make your UILabel has the size need it to wrap the content. So a good thing you could do is change the background to see if this line is do the job. 
I guess the problem is your constraints in the cell. You should have a look either looking at your code or your storyboards.
[Autolayout tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

Note: you should edit your question, otherwise you could get some negatives for this. If it is section 0 can not be section 1.

```
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
         if indexPath.section == 1 {
          /*your code */
         }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not using storyboards, this is created all programmatically.

Comment: you could add some constraints programmatially or show your code where you add it

Comment: The `textLabel` is not something I've created, it's what comes with the `tableView`. Its default position is centre in the cell, I just need to know if there's a way to align it vertically.